# PHP acess value of array using key of 2D array

Tags: php, arrays, magento, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a php magento script which have a array variable for store some script urls.

**array variable** `$items['js']`

**var_dump**

```
array(1) {
[""]=>
array(17) {
["prototype/prototype.js"]=>
string(22) "prototype/prototype.js"
["varien/form.js"]=>
string(14) "varien/form.js"
["mage/translate.js"]=>
string(17) "mage/translate.js"
["mage/cookies.js"]=>
string(15) "mage/cookies.js"
["wyomind/layer/native.history.js"]=>
string(31) "wyomind/layer/native.history.js"
["varien/weee.js"]=>
string(14) "varien/weee.js"
["geissweb/vatvalidation-min.js"]=>
string(29) "geissweb/vatvalidation-min.js"
}
}
```

**I tried to access the "geissweb/vatvalidation-min.js" value like this**

```
$items['js']['geissweb/vatvalidation-min.js']
```

but it return empty value, is there have a way to get that value without use foreach or for loop. Thank You

Comment: $items['js'][0]['geissweb/vatvalidation-min.js']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your index is '', shown by...

```
array(1) {
[""]=>
```

so you need to use...

```
$items['js']['']['geissweb/vatvalidation-min.js']
```

Comment: it's not different in any way from my answer. [''] and [0] are the same for PHP

Comment: If I change it to 0 in my test, I get 'Undefined offset'

Comment: @Hooli - `""` and `0` is **not** the same in php.

Answer (score 1):

You have your variable  `$items['js']` as an array of arrays what your looking for without a foreach is this :

```
$items['js'][0]['geissweb/vatvalidation-min.js'] is not valid
```

after tests

```
 $items['js'][""]['geissweb/vatvalidation-min.js'] is valid.
```

Comment: yes i notices another issue i come back to you in five after tests :)